# gsutil cp communications issues

Tags: python, cp, httplib, gsutil

Every friday I run a gsutil 4.3 cp -n -L -R command (python version is 2.7.5) in order to upload 5 GB of data (48 files no larger than 512 MB each one) from a Windows 7 Enterprise to GCS. Since August 8th, I began to get GSutil errors as the following:

- Caught BadStatusLine from httplib, retrying: ''
- Retrying request to url https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/offsite/o?fields=generation%2Cmd5Hash%2Csize&alt=json&upload_id=AEnB2UraXXAIW8wI-60MqMgu5Ae_zVoxSC_Wf1WfEkzoG--T51vsGRAYY1ZwrQriDhY-y-85tJX-b_Mu5bvE9Mt97eY2soi1_A&prettyPrint=True&uploadType=resumable after connection break.
- HTTP error on final retry: ''
- CommandException: md5 signature computed for local file (ClS2LyPSwjN1qHjP6ICSUQ==) doesn't match cloud-supplied digest (Yf0Fn4q+L8EhK7VQaugh+Q==). Cloud object (gs://file_URI) will be deleted.

I have also noted upload times are now very slow: this script used to take 3.5 hours to upload 5 GB and now it takes 12 hours until it gets interrupted by Windows Task Scheduler (because of the task timeouts configuration) having uploaded ~ 150 MB.

Although I understand that these errors may be related to network and/or communications issues, we have no other communications problems nor we have changed any communications device as firewalls, routers, etc. Also, it is not clear for me on which side are they being generated.

Any suggestion or idea in order to solve/workaround these issues?

Thank you very much in advance,
Federico

Comment: I'm having this problem a lot.

Did someone solved this problem?

Maybe adding [google-cloud-storage] should help the storage team to answer us.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed in v4.5.

Thanks Mike (from Google) for that info.